# FluentMigrator - add column to every table in loop

Tags: c#, fluent-migrator

I'm trying to create code that adds column 'ExternalId' to almost every table in foreach loop with some exceptions. If table schema name equals "Scheduler" or table name starts with "users" dont add column.

First this I probably need is a list of schemas and tables.

```
public class AddExternalIdColumnsToManyTables : Migration
{
    public override void Up()
    {
        // schema name example
        // Scheduler.Job

        // dbo.users_logins

        var schemaAndTableNames = new List<string>();

        foreach (var item in schemaAndTableNames)
        {
            if (item.StartsWith("Scheduler"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            if (item.Split('.')[1].StartsWith("users"))
            {
                continue;
            }

            Alter.Table(item.Split('.')[1]).AddColumn("ExternalId").AsInt32().Nullable();
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're asking how to get table names:

MigrationBase class (Migration's parent) has ConnectionsString property. You can easily get it and write ADO.net query to get table names. Simple example:

```
var builder = new SqlConnectionStringBuilder(ConnectionString);
var query = "SELECT TABLE_NAME" + 
            "FROM INFORMATION_SCHEMA.TABLES" + 
            "WHERE TABLE_TYPE = 'BASE TABLE' AND " +
            $"TABLE_CATALOG = '{builder.InitialCatalog}'"    

using (var connection = new SqlConnection(builder.ConnectionString))
{
    connection.Open();
    var command = new SqlCommand(query, connection);
    using (var sqlReader = command.ExecuteReader(CommandBehavior.KeyInfo))
    {
        var schemaTable = sqlReader.GetSchemaTable();
        foreach (DataRow row in schemaTable.Rows)
        {
              ///your table names
        }
    }
    connection.Close();
}
```